# Python BMI Calculator Syntax Error & Code Not Running Equation

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Syntax Error]

I still don't know what I am doing wrong? Why won't it take my named variables and square height and take the other and divide it by the square of the height?

Why is it indicating that the error is the name of the variable?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, post your code and errors in a [formatted code block](/help/formatting), e.g. py enclosing the code with tripple backticks (`>```<`)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Check out the guide to [ask] - specifically, before asking a question be sure to check whether there are other similar answers out there that resolve your question. There are many, many answers addressing how to deal with a SyntaxError - check out this [guide on realpython](https://realpython.com/invalid-syntax-python/). Hope this helps, and good luck getting started with python! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple fix on line 2 replace
Height = float(input("Enter weight in meters")
To
Height = float(input("Enter height in meters"))
As far as I can tell you just needed an extra bracket.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You forgor to close a bracket on line 2